# How to provide name of the Instance while creating aws ec2 using java aws sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am finding it very hard to figure out how to provide the *name* of ec2 instance while creating ec2 instance using Aws Java SDK.

I am using following method to create ec2 Instance-

```
  RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest();
            runInstancesRequest.withImageId(ec2Configuration.getImageId())
                    .withInstanceType(ec2Configuration.getInstanceType())
                    .withMinCount(ec2Configuration.getMincount())
                    .withMaxCount(ec2Configuration.getMaxcount())
                    .withKeyName(ec2Configuration.getKeyPairName())
                    .withSecurityGroupIds(Arrays.asList(ec2Configuration.getSgId()));
            if (ec2Configuration.isEbsOptimized())
                runInstancesRequest.withMonitoring(true);
            if (ec2Configuration.isEbsOptimized())
                runInstancesRequest.withEbsOptimized(true);
            try {
                RunInstancesResult result = amazonEC2Client.runInstances(
                        runInstancesRequest);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                // all exception stuffs
                }
```

I could not find anything anywhere like `.withName("myVmName").withInstanceType(...)` or `.define("myVmName").withInstanceType()`.

What is the way to set the name of Instance while creating an instance.

I want to give name given like the name 'cpanel' given in this image

[image: Check this image.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instances do not have a name, they instead have tags which are MetaData key values that are attached to the instance.

You will have a tag with the key of "Name".

What you would want to be looking at is the [withTagSpecifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/RunInstancesRequest.html#withTagSpecifications-com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.TagSpecification...-) argument.

Comment: Ohh my god!! Why didn't you come in my life earlier? You saved my life!! Thank you so much. I have been searching for it for too long.

Comment: Haha, glad I was of assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Tags , it will be your instance name

here is how you can give the name to your instance using AWS SDK 2.x

```
  private static final String TAG = "whatever you want to keep";
private static final String AMI_ID = "your_aws_AMI_ID";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final AmazonEC2 ec2 = Ec2Config.createEC2Client();

    RunInstancesRequest run_request = new RunInstancesRequest()
            .withImageId(AMI_ID)
            .withInstanceType(InstanceType.T1Micro)
            .withMaxCount(1)
            .withMinCount(1);

    RunInstancesResult run_response = ec2.runInstances(run_request);

    String reservation_id = run_response.getReservation().getInstances().get(0).getInstanceId();

        System.out.println("ReservationID :- "+ reservation_id);

    Tag tag = new Tag()
            .withKey("Name")
            .withValue(TAG);

    CreateTagsRequest tag_request = new CreateTagsRequest()
            .withResources(reservation_id)
            .withTags(tag);

    CreateTagsResult tag_response = ec2.createTags(tag_request);

    System.out.printf(
            "Successfully started EC2 instance %s based on AMI %s",
            reservation_id, AMI_ID);
}
```

Here is the whole method to create your instance with custom name